# Bluetooth Developer Studio connecting with real server (ibeacon)

Tags: ibeacon, bluetooth-lowenergy

Totally new in Bluetooth Developer Studio. How can I connect to actual physical ibeacon?

Using the HID over GATT profile in a new project, gives Workbench for interacting with a Virual Server. Can I connect directly to an actual ibeacon in range for read/write?

Comment: Why don't you try ?

Answer (score 0):

Understand that iBeacon is a transmit only standard, so there is no standard way of establishing a Bluetooth connection.  Beacons simply send out a Bluetooth LE advertisement at a periodic rate.

Some beacon manufacturers do have proprietary configuration GATT services which are connectable.  But the details of how you do so (if it is even possible) are specific to the manufacturer.

Comment: Thank you for this david! 
I will try to get a bit more specific: I have in hand an OEM ibeacon based on the TI cc2541 chipset.

I would like to at least be able to read its' transmissions' data through the Bletooth Developer Studio. Is this feasible?
Thanks again!

Comment: In other words, can I replace the "Virtual Server" in the Bluetooth Developer Studio with some actual real server?

Comment: *after doing my homework: 
I have a Belkin USB dongle attached. 

Is there any workaround for using OEM dongles instead of the "official" PTS bluetooth dongle?